# Shortening arduous and repetitive Numpy expressions

Tags: python, numpy, math

I'm working on some `Numpy` code, and it occurred to me that there must be a way to shorten long and/or repetitive expressions, such as these that I have in my code:

```
        A = array([[2 * (x_1 - x_2), 2 * (y_1 - y_2), 2 * (z_1 - z_2)],
                   [2 * (x_1 - x_3), 2 * (y_1 - y_3), 2 * (z_1 - z_3)],
                   [2 * (x_1 - x_4), 2 * (y_1 - y_4), 2 * (z_1 - z_4)],
                   [2 * (x_2 - x_3), 2 * (y_2 - y_3), 2 * (z_2 - z_3)],
                   [2 * (x_2 - x_4), 2 * (y_2 - y_4), 2 * (z_2 - z_4)],
                   [2 * (x_3 - x_4), 2 * (y_3 - y_4), 2 * (z_3 - z_4)]
                   ])

        b = array([c * c * (t_2 * t_2 - t_1 * t_1) + (x_1 * x_1 + y_1 * y_1 + z_1 * z_1) - (x_2 * x_2 + y_2 * y_2 + z_2 * z_2),
                   c * c * (t_3 * t_3 - t_1 * t_1) + (x_1 * x_1 + y_1 * y_1 + z_1 * z_1) - (x_3 * x_3 + y_3 * y_3 + z_3 * z_3),
                   c * c * (t_4 * t_4 - t_1 * t_1) + (x_1 * x_1 + y_1 * y_1 + z_1 * z_1) - (x_4 * x_4 + y_4 * y_4 + z_4 * z_4),
                   c * c * (t_3 * t_3 - t_2 * t_2) + (x_2 * x_2 + y_2 * y_2 + z_2 * z_2) - (x_3 * x_3 + y_3 * y_3 + z_3 * z_3),
                   c * c * (t_4 * t_4 - t_2 * t_2) + (x_2 * x_2 + y_2 * y_2 + z_2 * z_2) - (x_4 * x_4 + y_4 * y_4 + z_4 * z_4),
                   c * c * (t_4 * t_4 - t_3 * t_3) + (x_3 * x_3 + y_3 * y_3 + z_3 * z_3) - (x_4 * x_4 + y_4 * y_4 + z_4 * z_4)])
```

Where, for example, the expressions in matrix vector `b` are of the form:

`c**2 * ( t_j ** 2 - t_i ** 2) + (x_i ** 2 + y_i ** 2 + z_i ** 2) - (x_j ** 2 + y_j ** 2 + z_j ** 2)`

Now, in this particular example, it's not the end of the world. You could possibly also argue that shortening the expressions hinders readability in some sense. But, barring that, suppose I wanted to reduce the clutter, and I felt the equations were simple enough that I'm **not concerned about obscuring them**, even greatly.

What options do I have to reduce the need to repeat these equations, and/or to shorten them?

Comment: what is `x_1`, `x_2` etc?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga all variables (`x_1`, `x_2`, `t_1`, etc) are previously assigned floats (i.e. prior to this, in my code, I have `x_1 = 10.5`, e.g.).

Comment: Look for patterns that allow you to express it in terms of arrays like `x=np.array([x_1, x_2, ...]), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[x_1, y_1, z_1],
              [x_2, y_2, z_2],
              [x_3, y_3, z_3],
              [x_4, y_4, z_4]])

x, y, z = X.T

t = np.array([t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4])
```

And these convenient indexing arrays:

```
i, j = np.triu_indices(len(x), 1)
```

You could write:

```
A = np.c_[2 * (x[i] - x[j]), 2 * (y[i] - y[j]), 2 * (z[i] - z[j])]

b = c**2 * (t[j]**2 - t[i]**2) + (x[i]**2 + y[i]**2 + z[i]**2) - (x[j]**2 + y[j]**2 + z[j]**2)
```

Or a little bit more compact using the matrix `X`:

```
A = 2 * (X[i] - X[j])
b = c**2 * (t[j]**2 - t[i]**2) + (X[i]**2).sum(1) - (X[j]**2).sum(1)
```

The calculation for `b` can be made more efficient by precomputing some values:

```
t2 = t**2
X2s = (X**2).sum(axis=1)
b = c**2 * (t2[j] - t2[i]) + X2s[i] - X2s[j]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use list compresssion, mapping, itertools, etc.

Or you could simplify them the same way you can simplify matrices in mathematical equations when writing them out.
For example, it looks like you could pull 2 out of matrix A, and multiply it as a scalar instead:

```
A = np.array([x,y,z]) * 2
```